# Как нарисовать на canvas только часть картинки

Tags: javascript, изображения

есть 2 картинки и canvas, первая картинка рисуется полностью на весь canvas.
А вторую нужно показывать по частям, при чём не кругами или квадратами, а полигонами. Грубо говоря нужно сделать подсветку части картинки при наведении на неё, и обратное. (данная задача уже выполнена в плагине mapster для jquery, но мне нужно сделать без jquery, а библиотека без него не работает)

функция для определения в попадания точки в полигон есть

```
function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
    for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
        ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
        && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
        && (c = !c);
    return c;
}
```

и вот так я получаю полигоны на которые нужно реагировать:

```
var tmp2 = [],tmp,i,n,areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area'), len = areas.length, coords = [];
//в массиве areas все элементы по тегу area, len - его длина, coords - массив результата.
//идём по массиву areas и в массив tmp2 забиваем координаты, после этого забиваем 
//этот набор координат, как единое целое в массив результат coords - т.е. там 
//в итоге массив полигонов представленный точками
for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    tmp = areas[n].coords.split(',');
    for (i=0;i<tmp.length-1;i+=2)tmp2.push({x: tmp[i], y: tmp[i+1]});
    coords.push(tmp2);
    tmp2=[];
}
areas =[];
```

(результат в массиве - coords)

мапа в коде из которой получаем координаты

```
<map name="map1">
<area shape="poly" coords="16,107,68,107,68,159,16,159" alt="один" href="">
...
</map>
```

Comment: я конечно все понимаю но как мне прочитать ваш код хотя бы прокомментировали бы его

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, я добавил комментарии, стало яснее? функцию isPointInPoly можно просто принимать что она есть - принимает полигон и точку - возвращает входит ли точка в полигон..

Comment: можно сократить вопрос так - как вставить картинку в canvas имея массив точек обозначающий полигон в который надо её поместить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем нашел [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/getyoufun/ouy6dmcv/)(там есть описание на английском)
для себя же я сократил код так (по скольку мне не нужно делать обводку):

```
//пример параметра poly - [{x:2,y:2},{x:10,y:10},{x:50,y:50}]
//img2 - картинка которую хотим нарисовать
function drawpart(poly){
    var i=0;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(poly[0].x, poly[0].y);
    for(i =1;i<poly.length;i++)
    {
        ctx.lineTo(poly[i].x, poly[i].y);
    }
    ctx.clip(); 
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

всё отлично, только та функция для определения попадания точки в полигон работает не правильно.. буду рад ссылкам

Comment: функцию определения попадания заменил так - просто использую второй canvas на котором отрисовываю все эелементы заливая разными цветами и потом просто сравнивая точку под курсором определяю нужный объект, объектов мало, так что это подходит